# Make NOT NULL constraint apply only to new rows

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I will try to present the situation as a minimal example:

Say we have a table of tickets, defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ticket_id_list (
   ticket_id  NUMBER,
   issued_to  VARCHAR2(100),
   CONSTRAINT ticket_id_list_pk PRIMARY KEY (ticket_id)
);
```

The system is used for some time and data is added to the table:

```
INSERT INTO ticket_id_list (ticket_id, issued_to)
   VALUES (1, 'Arthur');
INSERT INTO ticket_id_list (ticket_id, issued_to)
   VALUES (2, 'Ford');
```

Later, following requirement pops up:

> We need to store a reference number to some other thing in the ticket table this point onwards. The reference needs to be ***non null***. But old records **must** have `NULL` values.

(Stupid as though this sound, this is a real requirement.)

Now if we do this:

```
ALTER TABLE ticket_id_list
   ADD ref_no VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL;
```

the constraint will be violated immediately and we will get: `ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column`.

We can of course add a check in the business logic, but that is cumbersome. And because of unexplainable reasons, we cannot use a default value. Is there a way to ***add a NOT NULL contraint that is only applicable to new records?***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add a check constraint where values after a certain date cannot be null; something like:

```
alter table ticket_id_list
  add constraint nul_ref
  check (ticket_id < 123456 or ref is not null);
```

This does presume that ticket_id's only go up over time, if you happen to have a date field in your table it maybe clearer to use that.

Answer (score 5):

I found a neat trick: [`NOVALIDATE`](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/novalidate-constraints-no-really/).

Add a nullable column:

```
ALTER TABLE ticket_id_list
   ADD ref_no VARCHAR2(6);
```

And then add a table contraint, but make sure to specify `NOVALIDATE`:

```
ALTER TABLE ticket_id_list
   ADD CONSTRAINT new_ref_nonull CHECK(ref_no IS NOT NULL) NOVALIDATE;
```

Now let's check it:

```
INSERT INTO ticket_id_list (ticket_id, issued_to, ref_no)
   VALUES (3, 'Zaphod', '2A4252');
1 row inserted

INSERT INTO ticket_id_list (ticket_id, issued_to, ref_no)
   VALUES (4, 'Marvin', NULL);
ORA-02290: check constraint (NEW_REF_NONULL) violated
```

Just as expected.

***Edit***: `NOVALIDATE` will work only if you need not to update the old rows. If you updated the old rows the constraint will fail. For this instance though, this is not an issue.

Comment: Now try to update some old row that has a `NULL` value.

Comment: @zerkms: Good point. But updating is not required. Reference number should not be updatable.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea because you may trick the optimizer.  It sometimes uses the table constraints to determine the plan.  It might get confused by things like this: `SELECT * FROM ticket_id_list WHERE ref_no IS NULL`.  I think it would be safer to write an INSERT trigger.

Comment: @WW.: Noted. But INSERT trigger is PL/SQL code. Would not it be slower than a contraint? I think I have to do a test to compare the two scenarios.

Comment: Yes, the trigger would be slower.  It's also not as obvious when someone describes the table that the column is not null.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to consider this requirement as a business logic since in you case it is.

Then implement this business logic in a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_ticket_id_list
    BEFORE INSERT ON ticket_id_list
    FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
         IF (:NEW is null) THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Cannot Insert 1 in this table');
         END IF;
      END;
```

Note - Same can be done for SQL Server as well [MSDN Create trigger documentations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but the question is tagged [tag:oracle]. And this is SQL Server.

Comment: Oops my bad. It's the same though for oracle. Edited for it.

Answer (score 0):

If the column you want to make the constraint as UNIQUE then it will allow all previous values would be nullable but all the new values should be unique and its default value should be Null.

But if the table column you want to make as NOT NULL, it should contain either the default value or any value should be specified implicitly.